# The Piggyback Sequence

Tags: code-golf, math

I made my own sequence recently (called the Piggyback sequence), and it works like this:

`P(1)`, `P(2)` and `P(3)` = `1`.

For all `P(n)` where `n>3`, the sequence works like this:

```
P(n) = P(n-3) + P(n-2)/P(n-1)
```

So, continuing the sequence:

`P(4)` = `1 + 1/1` = `2`

`P(5)` = `1 + 1/2` = `3/2`
= `1.5`

`P(6)` = `1 + 2/(3/2)` = `7/3`
= `2.33333...`

`P(7)` = `2 + (3/2)/(7/3)` = `37/14` = `2.6428571428...`

`P(8)` = `3/2 + (7/3)/(37/14)` = `529/222`
= `2.3828828828...`

Your task is, when given `n`, calculate `P(n)` either as a floating point number or an (im)proper fraction.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins.

*If anyone can find the name of the sequence, please edit the post accordingly.*

### Current leaders: MATL and Jelly (both at 15 bytes).

Comment: Can we start at index 0?  `P(0)=1`...

Comment: May I ask for the rationale behind the name you gave to this sequence?

Comment: @JanDvorak It just seems like the numbers are "piggybacking" each other.

Comment: @nimi Yes, you are allowed.

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, <strike>40</strike> 39 bytes.

```
f=lambda x:x<4or.0+f(x-3)+f(x-2)/f(x-1)
```

Gives `True` instead of 1, if this isn't allowed we can have this for 42 bytes:

```
f=lambda x:.0+(x<4or f(x-3)+f(x-2)/f(x-1))
```

The way it works is pretty straightforward, the only trick is using `.0+` to cast the result to a float.

Comment: You can save one byte by removing the space between `x<4` and `or`

Comment: In Python 2, you can use `f(x-1.)` to cast to float. In Python 3, you don't need to cast at all.

Answer (score 5):

### Haskel, 32 bytes

```
(a#b)c=a:(b#c)(a+b/c)
((0#1)1!!)
```

Usage example:  `((0#1)1!!) 7` -> `2.642857142857143`. I start the sequence with `0, 1, 1` to fix `!!`'s 0-based indexing.

Edit: @xnor found a way to switch from 0-based to 1-based index, without changing the byte count.

Comment: Nice method for beating the direct recursive definition. I think you can shift to 1-indexed by initializing `(0,1,1)`.

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 34 bytes

Since Ruby uses integer division by default, it turns out that it's shorter to use fractions instead. Golfing suggestions welcome.

```
f=->n{n<4?1r:f[n-3]+f[n-2]/f[n-1]}
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>25</s>  23 bytes

```perl6
{(0,1,1,1,*+*/*...*)[$_]}
```

```perl6
{(0,1,1,*+*/*...*)[$_]}
```

### Explanation:

```perl6
# bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣
{
  (
    # initial set-up
    # the ｢0｣ is for P(0) which isn't defined
    0, 1, 1, 1,

    # Whatever lambda implementing the algorithm
    * + * / *
    # { $^a + $^b / $^c }

    # keep using the lambda to generate new values until
    ...

    # Whatever (Forever)
    *

   # get the value indexed by the argument
  )[ $_ ]
}
```

This returns a [Rat](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Rat) ([Rational](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Rational)) for inputs starting with 3 up until the result would start having a denominator bigger than can fit in a 64 bit integer, at which point it starts returning [Num](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Num)s (floating point).
The last [Rat](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Rat) it will return is `P(11) == 8832072277617 / 2586200337022`

If you want it to return [Rational](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Rational) numbers rather than floats you can swap it for the following which will return a [FatRat](https://docs.perl6.org/type/FatRat) instead.

```perl6
{(0.FatRat,1,1,*+*/*...*)[$_]}
```

### Test:

```perl6
#! /usr/bin/env perl6
use v6.c;
use Test;

my &piggyback = {(0,1,1,*+*/*...*)[$_]}
# */ # stupid highlighter no Perl will ever have C/C++ comments

my @test = (
  1, 1, 1, 2,
  3/2, 7/3, 37/14,
  529 / 222,
  38242 / 11109,
  66065507 / 19809356,
  8832072277617 / 2586200337022,
);

plan +@test;

for 1..* Z @test -> ($input,$expected) {
  cmp-ok piggyback($input), &[==], $expected, $expected.perl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### C, 46 bytes

```c
float P(n){return n<4?1:P(n-3)+P(n-2)/P(n-1);}
```

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/aFNfck)

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 15 bytes

```
llli3-:"3$t/+]&
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=bGxsaTMtOiIzJHQvK10m&input=NQ)

#### Explanation

```
lll       % Push 1, 1, 1
i         % Take input n
3-:       % Pop n and push range [1 2 ... n-3] (empty if n<4)
"         % For each
  3$t     %    Duplicate the top three numbers in the stack
  /       %    Pop the top two numbers and push their division
  +       %    Pop the top two numbers and push their addition
]         % End
&         % Specify that the next function, which is implicit display, will take
          % only one input. So the top of the stack is displayed
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Cheddar](https://github.com/cheddar-lang/Cheddar), 31 bytes

```
n P->n<4?1:P(n-3)+P(n-2)/P(n-1)
```

The ungolfed version is so clear imo you don't need explanation:

```
n P->
  n < 4 ? 1 : P(n-3) + P(n-2) / P(n-1)
```

basically after the function arguments you can specify the variable to use which will be set to the function itself. Why? because this function will be tail-call-optimized, or at least should be.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
3Ld                # push list [1,1,1]
   ¹ÍG         }   # input-3 times do
      D3£          # duplicate list and take first 3 elements of the copy
         R`        # reverse and flatten
           /+      # divide then add
             ¸ì    # wrap in list and prepend to full list
                ¬  # get first element and implicitly print
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=M0xkwrnDjUdEM8KjUmAvK8K4w6x9wqw&input=OA)

Saved 1 byte thanks to Luis Mendo

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (ES6), 31 bytes

```
P=n=>n<4?1:P(n-3)+P(n-2)/P(n-1)
```

A simple function.

```js
P=n=>n<4?1:P(n-3)+P(n-2)/P(n-1)

var out = '';

for (var i=1;i <= 20;i++) {
out +='<strong>'+i+':</strong> '+P(i)+'<br/>';
}

document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = out;
```

```css
div {
font-family: Arial
}
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
```

Comment: Why not ES6? It saves a metric ton of bytes.

Comment: Like this: `P=n=>n<4?1:P(n-3)+P(n-2)/P(n-1)`

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Thanks. Frankly, I have no idea about the difference between the different Javascripts :D

Comment: To your advantage, on most challenges, you only need to know the "Big Arrow notation", which allows you to create functions without using the keyword `function`. The bit `P=n=>[...]` is creating an anonymous function that takes 1 parameter (n). Also, on ES6, returns are implicit. So, `P=n=>5` is a function that always returns `5`. You only need to enclose the body in `{}` if you have more than one statement (E.g.: `P=n=>{alert(1);console.log(1)}`). Since you have only 1 (big) statement (the ternary operator), you can forget the `{}`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Thanks, that will come in useful :D

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I helped you.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 20 bytes

```
L?<b4h0+y-b3cy-b2ytb
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%3F%3Cb4h0%2By-b3cy-b2ytb%0AyQ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ạ2,1,3ß€÷2/SµḊ¡
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bqhMiwxLDPDn-KCrMO3Mi9TwrXhuIrCoQ&input=&args=OA) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bqhMiwxLDPDn-KCrMO3Mi9TwrXhuIrCoQo4w4figqxZ&input=).

#### How it works

```
ạ2,1,3ß€÷2/SµḊ¡  Main link. Argument: n (integer)

             Ḋ   Dequeue; yield [2, ..., n].
            µ ¡  If the range is non-empty (i.e., if n > 1), execute the chain to
                 the left. If n is 0 or 1, return n.
                 Note that P(3) = P(0) + P(2)/P(1) if we define P(0) := 0.
ạ2,1,3           Take the absolute difference of n and 2, 1, and 3.
                 This gives [0, 1, 1] if n = 2, and P(0) + P(1)/P(1) = 0 + 1/1 = 1.
      ß€         Recursively apply the main each to each difference.
        ÷2/      Perform pairwise division.
                 This maps [P(n-2), P(n-1), P(n-3)] to [P(n-2)/P(n-1), P(n-3)].
           S     Sum, yielding P(n-2)/P(n-1) + P(n-3).
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 36 bytes

```
P@n_:=If[n<4,1,P[n-3]+P[n-2]/P[n-1]]
```

Here are the first few terms:

```
P /@ Range[10]
{1, 1, 1, 2, 3/2, 7/3, 37/14, 529/222, 38242/11109, 66065507/19809356}
```

Answer (score 1):

## R, <s>53</s> 47 bytes

```
f=function(N)ifelse(N>3,f(N-3)+f(N-2)/f(N-1),1)
```

This answer made use of the pretty neat function `ifelse` : `ifelse(Condition, WhatToDoIfTrue, WhatToDoIfNot)`

Comment: You should be able to get rid of the `return()` in your code. But you also need to name the function in order for your recursion to work

Answer (score 0):

## Dyalog APL, 25 bytes

`⊃{1↓⍵,⍎⍕' +÷',¨⍵}⍣⎕⊢0 1 1`